# JS error from radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<form style="align: center; position: absolute;">
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="groupA" value="A" checked>
  <label for="ref-annulus">A</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="groupB" value="B">
  <label for="ref-planet">B</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="groupC" value="C">
  <label for="ref-sun">C</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="groupD" value="D">
  <label for="ref-sun">D</label>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
var matrix_A = [
                [0,3,1,3,1,3,3],
                [1,0,3,1,3,2,1],
                [3,1,0,1,3,1,3],
                [1,3,3,0,3,3,3],
                [3,1,1,1,0,1,3],
                [1,3,3,1,3,0,3],
                [2,3,1,1,1,1,0]
               ],
var matrix_B = [
                [0,3,1,3,3,1,3],
                [1,0,1,3,3,3,3],
                [3,3,0,1,3,3,3],
                [1,1,3,0,1,1,3],
                [1,1,1,3,0,1,3],
                [3,1,1,3,3,0,3],
                [0,1,1,0,0,0,0]
               ];

var matrix = "matrix_"+$('input[name="group"]:checked').val();

console.log(matrix);
</script>
```

However, I expect to see that once clicking A button, the 'maxtrix' variable would automatically call matrix_A and if clicking button B, it would automatically call matrix_B. But it didn't.

Can you please help me to troubleshooting this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are executing your JavaScript code once when the page loads and then never again.  Instead, you should put a [`.on` listener](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for clicks of the radio buttons and reevaluate which is the clicked one.  There are many ways to do this, probably better than I have here, but this is a simple example of how to accomplish what you are looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var matrix_A = [
                  [0,3,1,3,1,3,3],
                  [1,0,3,1,3,2,1],
                  [3,1,0,1,3,1,3],
                  [1,3,3,0,3,3,3],
                  [3,1,1,1,0,1,3],
                  [1,3,3,1,3,0,3],
                  [2,3,1,1,1,1,0]
                 ];
  var matrix_B = [
                  [0,3,1,3,3,1,3],
                  [1,0,1,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,0,1,3,3,3],
                  [1,1,3,0,1,1,3],
                  [1,1,1,3,0,1,3],
                  [3,1,1,3,3,0,3],
                  [0,1,1,0,0,0,0]
                 ];
  function evaluateMatrix(){
    var matrix = "matrix_"+$('input[name="group"]:checked').val();
    console.log(matrix);
  }
  
  $(document).on('click', 'input[name="group"]', evaluateMatrix);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form style="align: center; position: absolute;">
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="groupA" value="A" checked>
  <label for="ref-annulus">A</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="groupB" value="B">
  <label for="ref-planet">B</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="groupC" value="C">
  <label for="ref-sun">C</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="groupD" value="D">
  <label for="ref-sun">D</label>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want to output the matrix_A's value?

i think you can try `eval`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form style="align: center; position: absolute;">
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="groupA" value="A" checked>
  <label for="ref-annulus">A</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="groupB" value="B">
  <label for="ref-planet">B</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="groupC" value="C">
  <label for="ref-sun">C</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="groupD" value="D">
  <label for="ref-sun">D</label>
</form>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var matrix_A = [
                  [0,3,1,3,1,3,3],
                  [1,0,3,1,3,2,1],
                  [3,1,0,1,3,1,3],
                  [1,3,3,0,3,3,3],
                  [3,1,1,1,0,1,3],
                  [1,3,3,1,3,0,3],
                  [2,3,1,1,1,1,0]
                 ];
  var matrix_B = [
                  [1,3,1,3,3,1,3],
                  [1,0,1,3,3,3,3],
                  [3,3,0,1,3,3,3],
                  [1,1,3,0,1,1,3],
                  [1,1,1,3,0,1,3],
                  [3,1,1,3,3,0,3],
                  [0,1,1,0,0,0,0]
                 ];
  $("input:radio").click(function(){
    var matrix = "matrix_"+$('input[name="group"]:checked').val();
    console.log(eval(matrix));
  })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you find yourself trying to access a variable name dynamically, you should be using an array or object. So instead of two variables `matrix_A` and `matrix_B`, you should create a single matrix `matrixes` that contains an object whose keys are the matrix names.

```
var matrixes = {
  A: [
    [0, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3],
    [1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1],
    [3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 3],
    [1, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3],
    [3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3],
    [1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3],
    [2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
  ],
  B: [
    [0, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3],
    [1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    [3, 3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3],
    [1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3],
    [1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3],
    [3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 3],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ]
};

var matrix = matrixes[$('input[name="group"]:checked').val()];
```

To execute this when the user clicks on one of the radio buttons, put it in a click event handler.

```
var matrix;
$(":radio[name=group]").click(function() {
    matrix = matrixes[$(this).val()];
});
```

You don't need the `:clicked` selector, because clicking on a radio button always makes that one the selected option.

Comment: Barmar, your solution works for me well. But the matrix only pick up group where attribute is 'checked'.

Comment: I thought that was the intended behavior.

Comment: Of course, if you want this to change whenever you click on a button, you need to put the code into an event handler that runs when they click.

Comment: How can you be programming with jQuery and not know how to write a click handler?